# Will ROS lunar run on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ros-lunar, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will the ROS distribution lunar run on the Ubuntu 18.04?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284184/will-ros-lunar-run-on-ubuntu-18.04?/) by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2018-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is slightly difficult to answer, as you ask "will it run?", which is different from "is it supported?".

As to supported: no, Lunar is not supported on `18.04`. See [REP 3: Platforms by Distribution - Lunar Loggerhead](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019), which shows that Lunar is only supported on `16.04`, `16.10` (might not be the case any more) and `17.04`.

('supported' in this case means that official binaries are made available and those are guaranteed to work on a specific OS)

As to "will it run": a from-source build (using the steps outlined in [wiki/lunar/Installation/Source](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Source)) *may* succeed, but there are no guarantees. There are many questions about building ROS from source on various OS, even newer and older Ubuntu versions. See #q277021 for an example.

Perhaps another board member can tell you more conclusively whether they've been able to build Lunar on `18.04` from source.

---

Note that ROS Melodic is / will be supported on `18.04`: [REP 3: Platforms by Distribution - Melodic Morenia](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-02**:
And, as always: running ROS on any 'unsupported' OS is definitely possible with something like Docker. The OSRF supplies Docker images for just about every ROS release there is.

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2018-03-02**:
Ok thanks!
And is there any ROS distribution that is officially supported by Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-02**:
Well, I would say check REP-3. I linked you to it twice. That contains all the info you need.

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2018-03-05**:
Thank you!